# How to correctly use panda's slice/replace with values form another column and then explode a row into two

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string

I'm working with a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
   ID         SEQ BEG_GAP END_GAP  
0  A1     ABCDEFG       2       4  
1  B1     YUUAAMN       4       6
2  C1  LKHUTYYYYA       7       9
```

And what I'm trying to do is basically first replace the part of the string in `"SEQ"` that's in between the values of `"BEG_GAP"` and `"END_GAP"`, to then explode the two pieces of the string left into two different lines (probably using Panda's explode).

I.e: First expected result:

```
   ID         SEQ BEG_GAP END_GAP  
0  A1     AB---FG       2       4  
1  B1     YUUA---       4       6
2  C1  LKHUTY--YA       7       8
```

To then get:

```
   ID         SEQ BEG_GAP END_GAP  
0  A1          AB       2       4  
1  A1          FG       2       4 
2  B1        YUUA       4       6
3  C1      LKHUTY       7       8
4  C1          YA       7       8
```

I'm trying to use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("..\path_to_the_csv.csv")

for index, rows in df.iterrows():
    start = df["BEG_GAP"].astype(float)
    stop= df["END_GAP"].astype(float)
   
    df["SEQ"] = df["SEQ"].astype(str)
    df['SEQ'] = df['SEQ'].str.slice_replace(start=start,stop=stop,repl='-')
```

But the column `"SEQ"` that I'm getting is full of NaN. I suppose it has to do with how I'm using start and stop. I could use some help with this, and also with how to later divide the rows according to the gaps.
I hope I was clear enough, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try:

```
df['SEQ'] = df.apply(lambda x: [x.SEQ[:x.BEG_GAP], x.SEQ[x.END_GAP+1:]], axis=1)

output = df.explode('SEQ').query('SEQ!=""')
```

Output:

```
   ID      SEQ  BEG_GAP  END_GAP
0  A1       AB        2        4
0  A1       FG        2        4
1  B1     YUUA        4        6
2  C1  LKHUTYY        7        8
2  C1        A        7        8
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! I had to do `df[BEG_GAP].astype(int)` just before so it worked properly. Thanks!!